# Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 cannot deploy a Web Project via WebDeploy v2.0+

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am receiving the following error when attempting to publish a Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 project ...

```
Error 1 The "VSMSDeploy" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: Version string portion was too short or too long.
   at System.Version.VersionResult
          .SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String argument)
   at System.Version.TryParseVersion(String version, VersionResult& result)
   at System.Version.Parse(String input)
   at System.Version..ctor(String version)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Common.Utility.CheckMSDeploymentVersion()
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Common.Utility.get_IsMSDeployInstalled()
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Common.Utility
          .CheckMSDeploymentVersion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeploy.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd
          .ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(
          ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, 
          TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, 
          TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, 
          TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)  
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v1.0\
          Microsoft.LightSwitch.targets 96410Application3
```

I have tried re-installing Web Deploy (both 2.0, via the website, and 2.1, via the WebPI) but no joy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 requires Web Deploy 1.1 which was not installed by its installer (2.0 had previously been installed by WebMatrix and I also tried 2.1 via the WebPI). My problem was solved after I downloaded it from the Microsoft Download Center:

- [Web Deployment Tool (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4148)
- [Web Deployment Tool (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24709)

*This did make me wonder why LightSwitch doesn't support WebDeploy 2.0/2.1, and also installs SQL Server Express 2008 rather than 2008 R2, but that is a question for another time*